# MVC and co-dependent classes in c++

Tags: c++, winapi, model-view-controller

**EDIT:**

what I did instead was to move the "Main Window" creation and message handler into the controller, now only controller needs to know about Model and View. Since main window messages are processed in the controller itself, it can easily call view to change, and call model to do the logic, view never needs to call model, and if model needs to talk to View, then there are 3 options:

1. It can do so by returning a value to the calls from Model and then Model calls View according to what is returned from Model.
2. Model can post WM_APP messages to the main window  and then Model calls View accordingly.
3. If the changes are very small, for instance, changing text of a static control, the Controller can pass handles to those controls to Model and Model can do the changes itself.

Any advices ?

---

I am trying to understand how MVC work in c++ and pure winapi, so am developing a demo app, and trying to implement my own interpretation/version of MVC.
The idea is to keep controller in total control, where everything is relayed through the controller.

Design :

Every class will be in it's own file .h and .cpp
Our main.cpp,view classes and model classes all will only be able to communicate to controller and controller only, there won't be any communication between then directly.

1. **The view classes**(there will be more then 1 gui(child windows) including the main window gui) will only create, show, hide, and destroy the windows(views) the messageloop of the main window and any sub or superclassesed child window will reside either in the controller folder or in the model folder.
2. **Controller** will further have sub folders with files views.h, views.cpp for communicating to view classes and model.h, model.cpp for communicating to model classes, similar in structure as in views.
3. **Model** will have files with different logics related to the application in different files.

It will look something like :

[image]

Problem :
There are too many co-dependent classes in different files.

What kind of approach would you suggest, I want to keep the idea of "*Everything relaying through controller*", if possible.

Answer (score 4):

What's missing is some kind of **abstract interfaces for the view and model to communicate**. I.e., you rely on concrete types for communication.

This can be solved in a few different ways:

- Abstract base classes as listeners/observers, (i.e. `IModelListener`, `IViewListener`) which the controller implements.
- Events (i.e. `ValueEnteredEvent` from view and `ValueChangedEvent` from model).
- Slots & signals ala Qt (or Boost), which allows a listener to connect to single output methods of an object.

The controller connects to the view and model object respectively, using whatever method you prefer. Hence, these do not know about the controller directly, they only talk to these given interfaces.

- Avoid concrete dependencies & connections.
- Abstract them away through interfaces (defined by the object it self)
- Make sure each object knows as little as possible (but no less) in order to communicate effectively with it's peers.

Comment: I am not sure if I understood it correctly, it was much easier in JAVA :P : Please have a look at Edit above for What I did instead.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do this using pipes

The controller will have open pipes to the model class and the view class.
The view will have open pipes to the child view classes.

When a child view makes a change to the data, it sends the change to the main view through the pipe.

The view in turn sends the change to the controller through the pipe.

The controller updates the model by writing to the pipe.

The model updates the data and sends the refreshed data to the controller.

The controller sends the refreshed data to the main view.

The view then sends the refreshed data to the child views.

All communication is done by reading and writing to the respective pipes.

Answer (score 0):

What I'm doing on MVC pattern is I create a ViewDelegate which is an abstract class. Make my controller inherited from ViewDelegate, and set controller as View's delegate.

```
    Class ViewDelegate{
Public:
     Virtual void onViewCallBack = 0;
}

    Class controller : public ViewDelegate{
Public:
       Static Controller* create();
Private:
       Bool init();
       Void onViewCallBack();
}

    Class view {
Public:
static view* create();
Bool initWithDelegate(ViewDelegate*)
Private:
Bool init();

}
```

Use the delegate in View to call method declare in Controller.

Comment: thanks for the editing, not used to the form on phone.